# Context API, Cannot retreive the data I am setting in seperate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a little project of mine but ran into an issue while working with the so called `Context API`. First time doing it as well.

The issue I am having is that I am unable to console.log the data I am setting. Now I am trying to make a "Add To Cart" button, and whenever the button is pressed. An object containing things such as name, price, color etc will be sent over to my ShoppingCart component.

I am able to set the value, whenever I press the button. And it appears in the console.log. Though, I am unable to console.log the value from ShoppingCart.

My files look like this:

```
./Contexts
   ./AddToCartContext.js
./Components
   ./Product
     ./ProductContent.js  // Here the "add to cart" button is located.
   ./ShoppingCart
     ./ShoppingCart.js // Here I need the data from ProductContent.js
App.js
```

Here is my App.js code:

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState({});
console.log(cartItems); // The data is being logged here perfectly.

return (
    <AddToCartContext.Provider value={{ cartItems, setCartItems }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
        {/* GlobalStyles skapas i ./themes.js */}
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <ShoppingCart theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/category/:type/:id/:productid">
            <FetchAPI />
          </Route>
          // ...
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AddToCartContext.Provider>
);
```

Here is my shoppingcart.js code:

```
import { AddToCartContext } from "../../Contexts/AddToCartContext";

const ShoppingCart = (props) => {
  const { cartItems } = useContext(AddToCartContext);
  console.log(cartItems); // This always result in an empty Object.
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TopNavigation />
      <BottomNavigation theme={props.theme} toggleTheme={props.toggleTheme} />
      <Cart />
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

And here is the code in ProductContent.js (shorten as its pretty long):

```
import { AddToCartContext } from "../../Contexts/AddToCartContext";
const ProductContent = (props) => {
const { setCartItems } = useContext(AddToCartContext);
return (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() =>
                      setCartItems({ // This returns the object to App.js, but not Shoppingcart.js
                        name: props.name,
                        price: props.price,
                        color: props.mainImg?.colour,
                        img: props.mainImg?.url,
                        id: params.productid,
                      })
                    }
                    className={classes.add_to_cart}
                  >
                    <Cart />
                    add to cart
                  </button>
);
}
```

As mentioned, it's the first time I work with Context API. Am I missing anything?

EDIT:

Did some testing, and if I set the initial value on `const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState({});` to for example "test", then it is being rendered inside of the Cart page.

Nothing is logging inside of the cart upon the button press. But whenever the initial value is set to "test" it is loaded instantly.

Here is the code for creating the context (AddToCartContext.js):

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AddToCartContext = createContext({});
```

Comment: how are you creating the context ?

Comment: Forgot to add, edited the bost! @Shyam

Comment: Created a code sandbox and tried to mimic your code . It seems to work fine . https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-haibt-u40y0?file=/src/App.js:326-333

Comment: Strange, I'll read it through and see if I can get anything to work.

Comment: are you using `AddToCartContext.Provider` anywhere else apart from your `App.js`

Comment: Changed my code to the sandbox you made, but did not work. And no, I only have one `AddToCartContext.Provider`, and that is located in `App.js`. I have read that there are consumer as well, is that supposed to be in cart?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232777/discussion-between-shyam-and-simon-sjoo).

Answer (score 0):

try without destructuring like this below

```js
  const  cartItems  = useContext(AddToCartContext);

  console.log(cartItems);
```

and check if there is anything in that object

Comment: Tried this, the object is still empty. Though, I have to reload the "cart" page, could this perhaps make the state empty again?

Comment: you passed here empty object, try some defualt value, for checking.

const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState({});

Comment: I updated my post with some extra information, including the code I used to create my context.

Comment: what you mean by reload ? you mean like refresh. If yes then your app is rendered from scratch resulting the state getting initialized again .

Comment: @Shyam yes, that I know. But the data from `cartItems` is not loading from the cart at all. So if I click "Add To Cart" button, it doesn't log anything at all inside of `ShoppingCart.js`. But it logs from `App.js`.